# AWS Cloudformation VPCPeeringConnection between two public VPC's

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have big AWS Cloudformation and have task to separate some of the resources with two VPC's. Both should be with public resources and in the same availability zones. They can use the same InternetGateway. It just additional security task.

And I little bit confused.

From examples I see that I should use VPCPeeringConnection like that:

```json
    "myVPCPeeringConnection": {
           "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCPeeringConnection",
            "Properties": {
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "myVPC"},
                "PeerVpcId": {"Ref": "myPrivateVPC"}
            }
     }
```

But they put peering between resources that public and private, and I need to peer two between public resources in VPC's.

Should I create for each of them separate subnets, RouteTable, InternetGateway, VPCGatewayAttachment,PublicNetworkAcl, Route too?
Or I can use all of them for both?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr -- Provision the two VPCs with their own independent sets of all the resources that each of them needs.

> They can use the same Internet Gateway.

No, they can't.  Internet Gateways, NAT Instances, NAT Gateways, VPNs, Direct Connect, and VPC Service Endpoints can't be shared across peering connections.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/invalid-peering-configurations.html#edge-to-edge-vgw

The same is true for route tables.  In peered VPCs, the route tables must necessarily be different, because each VPC needs routes to point to the other.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Route_Tables.html#route-tables-vpc-peering

And, of course, the subnets in each VPC must also not overlap, or peering is impossible.

> But they put peering between public and private, and I need to peer two between public VPC's.

This is arbitrary terminology.  There is not really any such distinction as "public" or "private" with regard to VPCs.

Whether a VPC is consideree public or private is simply an arbitrary designation related to how you use the VPC -- you might, for example, have databases in a VPC that you call "private" and web servers in a VPC you call "public," but there is no firm technical distinction between the two "different" types of VPCs.

Comment: Thanks. About public or private I spoke about resources that should be in VPC's. I edit my question and specified resources.

Comment: @muzafarow that makes sense, although it doesn't really change my interpretation of the question.